# PowerShell in command prompt issue, 'Format-Table' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, command-prompt

I am executing powershell script in cmd.

First i write command

`C:\Windows\system32>start powershell.exe Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`

it works successfully

than for running script i write command

```
C:\Windows\system32>start powershell.exe C:\\Get-NetworkStatistics.ps1
```

It also works successfully

the problem is when i try to run the function

```
    C:\Windows\system32>start powershell.exe Get-NetworkStatistics -computername Gbsi1  | Format-Table -autosize
```

it gives error that "'Format-Table' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

here is the screenshot for it.
[image]

It runs successfully in powershell but no in cmd. Is there any issue with pipe | which i put before Format-Table

Answer (score 5):

As your it is, the pipe is interpreted by `CMD` not powershell. 
Thus, `CMD` will try to execute a command named `Format-Table`, which does not exist (outside powershell).

You can escape it using `^`:

```
start powershell.exe Get-NetworkStatistics -computername Gbsi1 ^| Format-Table -autosize
```

Or by quoting the complete command line

```
start powershell.exe "Get-NetworkStatistics -computername Gbsi1 | Format-Table -autosize"
```

Note that your invocation is errnous anyhow, you need to provide the `-Command` option to powershell, like so:

```
start powershell.exe -Command "Get-NetworkStatistics -computername Gbsi1 | Format-Table -autosize"
```

Finally, do you really want to use `start`? It will open a new window, that will close immediately after the command is through. You could also use:

```
powershell.exe -Command "Get-NetworkStatistics -computername Gbsi1 | Format-Table -autosize"
```